# How to bind String[] to Collection of POJOs?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a binder which gets a string of permissions and must convert it to the Collection. But when binder method is invoking it can’t convert array of String to collection.

My controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/profile")
public class ProfileController {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mvcUserService")
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editForm(Principal principal) {
        User user = userService.getUser(principal.getName());
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("user/profile");
        return mav.addObject("user", user);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ModelAndView edit(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result) {
        // some action with User object
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Permission.class, new PropertyEditorSupport() {
            @Override
            public void setAsText(String name) throws IllegalArgumentException {
                Permission permission = userService.getPermission(name);
                setValue(permission);
            }
        });
```

JSP:

```
<form:form action="/profile/edit" method="PUT" modelAttribute="user">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/>

// setting up fields

<form:hidden path="id"/>
<form:hidden path="permissions"/>
</form:form>
```

Permission class:

```
public class Permission implements Serializable {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
```

And my User class:

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    // some fields

    private Collection<Permission> permissions;
```

I need to implement correct binding. Any suggestions how can I do it?

Comment: Is it calling the binding at all?  Or throwing an error?

Comment: It's calling binding.

Comment: So what's not working?  From your example, you don't seem to be sending a String[] or anything.

Comment: In my binder I'm getting permissions as single string "edit_user, delete_user". But my binder cannot convert it to the Collection<Permission>.

Comment: My understanding is that Spring MVC already knows how to handle the collecitons part, just not the bean part.  Are you saying it's not working that way?

Comment: Yes it is. I think Spring cannot convert String to bean in my binder.

Comment: Ok, so I am very confused here.  You say that your binder is running, but Spring isn't converting the String to your bean.  So, is the binder running or not?  If it's running and throwing an error, can you provide the error?  When I say "running your binder", I am specifically asking is it running the setAsTest() on your custom PropertyEditorSupport.

Comment: No I didn't have PropertyEditorSuppor.

Comment: It's right there in your `initBinder()` method.  You register a custom `PropertyEditorSupport` to handle your `Permission.class`.  Is the `setAsText()` method of that actually running?

Comment: I figured out right now that my PropertyEditorSupport didn't work at all. Method setAsText() isn't invoking. On my controller I'm getting Collection<Permission> but with id = null. Only name of permission has been setted correct.

Comment: In your setAsText method name varaible has "edit_user, delete_user" string ? , is that you are trying to say

Comment: Not exactly. I'm getting LinkedHashSet of Permissions with Permission.name = "edit_user", but Permission.id = null. Seams all objects of collection are incomplete.

Comment: You are not setting the ID in your PropertyEditorSupport implementation, on the name.  Why do you think the ID would be set?

Answer (score 0):

Your editor seems to lack the logic to convert CSV list into a list of objects. Here is the code for PermissionListEditor which will convert comma-separated list of strings to/from List collection:

```
public class PermissionListEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

  @Override
  public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    List<Permission> res = new ArrayList();
    for (String v: text.split(",")) {
      if (v.trim().length() > 0)
        res.add(userService.getPermission(v.trim()));
    }
    setValue(res);
  }

  @Override
  public String getAsText() {
    StringBuilder val = new StringBuilder();
    for (Permission p: (List<Permission>) getValue()) {
      if (val.length() > 0) val.append(", ");
      val.append(p.getName());
    }
    return val.toString();
  }

}
```

It is probably a good idea to add some sort of a map to lookup Permission objects from instead of fetching them from database one-by one. Something like this in the constructor:

```
Map<String, Permission> map = new HashMap()<>;
for (Permission p: userService.listPermissions();
  map.add(p.getName(), p);
```

and then just retrieve objects from that map in setAsText() method:

```
res.add(map.get(v.trim());
```

hope that helps.